# Is it possible to delete the aws Security Group Default Egress allow all Rule with Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I Know that terraform does remove the default behavior of AWS.But is it possible to do that with the cloudformation ?

Answer (score 8):

The CloudFormation documentation has a dedicated section for that:

- [Remove Default Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#aws-properties-ec2-security-group--examples--Remove_Default_Rule):

> When you specify a VPC security group, Amazon EC2 creates a default egress rule that allows egress traffic on all ports and IP protocols to any location. The default rule is removed only when you specify one or more egress rules. **If you want to remove the default rule and limit egress traffic to just the localhost (127.0.0.1/32)**, use the following example.

```
sgwithoutegress:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: Limits security group egress traffic
    SecurityGroupEgress:
    - CidrIp: 127.0.0.1/32
      IpProtocol: "-1"
    VpcId:
      Ref: myVPC
```

Not that this **does not remove physically** the egress rule from the security group. This will lead to the following egress rule being created:

[image]

Instead of the default one:

[image]

Comment: Yes..it allows through a rule ... But I don't want to have any rule in the outbound at all... Is it possible with Cloudformation ?

Answer (score 0):

That should work when you need custom traffic.

```yaml
ProjectABuildSecurityGroup:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: Security group
    VpcId: vpc-<id>
    SecurityGroupEgress:
      - Description: Allow to 443
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 443
        ToPort: 443
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - Description: Allow to 80
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement that need to remove the inbound and outbound rules for the Default SG that created from CFN when create a VPC.

There has an open issue in GitHub but it still not provide any solution on it.

[GitHub-Open-issus](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/658)

As the link mentioned, there only able to remove the inbound and outbound rules using CFN Custom Resources and AWS CLI,  I will provide these 2 work a round here.

AWS CLI way:

```
# aws ec2 revoke-security-group-egress --group-id "<default-sg-id>" --protocol all --port all --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
# aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id "<default-sg-id>" --protocol all --port all --source-group <default-sg-id>
```

Custom Reources:

```
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  LambdaBasicExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: yliu-custom-resource-lambda
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: '*'
                Resource: '*'

  CustomSGResource:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt 'CustomFunction.Arn'
      GroupIds: !GetAtt VPC.DefaultSecurityGroup

  CustomFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Description: "Retrieves EC2 Security group name"
      Timeout: 30
      Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaBasicExecutionRole.Arn'
      Runtime: python3.7
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import json
          import logging
          import cfnresponse
          import boto3
          
          logger = logging.getLogger()
          logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
            logger.info('got event {}'.format(event))  
            try: 
              responseData = {}
              if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
                logger.info('Incoming RequestType: Delete operation') 
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, {})


              if event['RequestType'] in ["Create", "Update"]:                      
                # 1. retrieve resource reference ID or Name
                GroupId=event['ResourceProperties']['GroupIds']
                # 2. retrieve boto3 client    
                ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
                # 3. Invoke describe/retrieve function using ResourceRef
                ec2_client.revoke_security_group_egress(
                  GroupId=GroupId,
                  IpPermissions=[{
                    'IpProtocol': '-1',
                    'IpRanges': [
                    {
                      'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0',
                    },]
                    }]
                  )
                ec2_client.revoke_security_group_ingress(
                  GroupId=GroupId,
                  IpPermissions=[{
                    'IpProtocol': '-1',
                    'UserIdGroupPairs': [
                      {
                          'GroupId': GroupId,
                      },]
                    }]
                  )
                responseData = {}
                logger.info('Remove Defefault Security group inbound and outbound rules')
                responseData['message']= 'Remove Defefault Security group inbound and outbound rules'
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
              else:
                logger.info('Unexpected RequestType!') 
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
            except Exception as err:
              logger.error(err)
              responseData = {"Data": str(err)}
              cfnresponse.send(event,context,cfnresponse.FAILED,responseData)
            return
```

I hope the information is helpful.